# Drop-down-list in php+mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I would like to create drop down list with options that are selected from my mysql database. And i have problem becouse when i try it this way my page is like "Error 500".`

```
$filmsar = array();
$vare = 0;

        $result_films = mysql_query("SELECT `film_name` FROM `films`");
                while($row_film = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_films))
                {
                     $filmsar[$vare]=$row_film["film_name"];
                      $vare++;
                }
```

This is how i load my data. And now this is how i'm trying to create drop down list:

```
            Jaki film:<br>
        <select name="film_id_name">'
        for($i = 0; $i<$vare;$i++){
        '<option>'.$filmsar[i].'</option>'}'
    <option>Tu wpisz pierwszą możliwość</option>
    <option>Tu wpisz drugą możliwość</option>
</select>
```

I would be greatful for any help.

Comment: Check your logs for clues on what's gone wrong. Take a look at [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and 
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), they will tell you exactly what's wrong. I'd take a *wild guess* that there's something missing where you try to create the dynamic dropdown.

Comment: `mysql_*` has been deprecated for over 2 years now. Please update your code to MySQLi or PDO before even continuing. As for the 500 error: Check your server logs. It's the first place to look.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion to look at logs was a briliant idea. I totaly forgot about them. I know mysql_* is depreacted but it's website for my studies and it's kinda imposed.

Answer (score 0):

50* Errors are server errors, so u should search for errors in ur server side language (PHP in this scenerio).

In this case i would wonder if u're using old enough version of php to use mysql_query (since it's depracated from PHP 5.5).

Instead of this, learn how to use PDO.